Meaning of sequence 11011010000000111000000000
What is the meaning and significance of the following sequence of digits?
11011010000000111000000000

Hint:

 This sequence corresponds to "lowercase". There is another related sequence that corresponds to "uppercase".



 These 26 digits map to the lowercase letters of the alphabet, with a '1' indicating that the character includes a closed loop, such as 'a' or 'b', but not c.


upvote and related "uppercase" sequence: 11010000000000111100000000
